# How to remove all packages (libxcb1) that were used by xorg-edgers packages and install ubuntu's packages?

Tags: apt

I have a problem with uninstalling packages that were used by xorg-edgers' version of nvidia drivers that I have installed and after that removed (331.20), e.g.:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libxcb
ii  libxcb-composite0:amd64                1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, composite extension
ii  libxcb-dri2-0:amd64                    1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, dri2 extension
ii  libxcb-dri3-0:amd64                    1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, dri3 extension
ii  libxcb-glx0:amd64                      1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, glx extension
ii  libxcb-icccm4:amd64                    0.3.9-2                                          amd64        utility libraries for X C Binding -- icccm
ii  libxcb-image0:amd64                    0.3.9-1ubuntu1                                   amd64        utility libraries for X C Binding -- image
ii  libxcb-keysyms1:amd64                  0.3.9-1                                          amd64        utility libraries for X C Binding -- keysyms
ii  libxcb-present0:amd64                  1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, present extension
ii  libxcb-randr0:amd64                    1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, randr extension
ii  libxcb-render-util0:amd64              0.3.8-1.1                                        amd64        utility libraries for X C Binding -- render-util
ii  libxcb-render0:amd64                   1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, render extension
ii  libxcb-shape0:amd64                    1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, shape extension
ii  libxcb-shm0:amd64                      1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, shm extension
ii  libxcb-sync0:amd64                     1.9.1-3ubuntu1                                   amd64        X C Binding, sync extension
ii  libxcb-sync1:amd64                     1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, sync extension
ii  libxcb-util0:amd64                     0.3.8-2build1                                    amd64        utility libraries for X C Binding -- atom, aux and event
ii  libxcb-xfixes0:amd64                   1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, xfixes extension
ii  libxcb-xv0:amd64                       1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding, xv extension
ii  libxcb1:amd64                          1.10-1~xedgers~saucy1                            amd64        X C Binding
```

That causes other problems with dependencies. Therefore I would like to uninstall them, and install versions provided by Ubuntu, e.g.: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/libxcb1/1.9.1-3ubuntu1

But when I try to remove them (I may as well remove the whole system):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libxcb1:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  content-hub deluge-common extlinux fonts-texgyre gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gsettings-ubuntu-touch-schemas icoutils kate-data kde-runtime-data kdelibs5-data libandroid-properties1
  libattica0.4 libboost-program-options1.53.0 libboost-python1.53.0 libc-ares2 libcontent-hub0 libcpufreq0 libdee-qt5-3 libdlrestrictions1 libepub0 libgflags2 libgfortran3 libgif4
  libgoogle-glog0 libgsettings-qt1 libhardware2 libhud2 libhybris libhybris-common1 libkactivities6 libkdecore5 libkjsapi4 libkntlm4 libkonq5-templates libkpty4 liblapack3 libmedia1
  libmikmod2 libmirclient3 libmirprotobuf0 libnepomukcleaner4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libofono-qt1 libpam-ck-connector libportmidi0 libqapt2 libqdjango-db0 libqt5organizer5
  libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libsmi2ldbl libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsystemsettings1 libthreadweaver4
  libtorrent-rasterbar7 libubuntu-application-api1 libubuntu-location-service0 libubuntu-platform-hardware-api1 libubuntudownloadmanager1 libunity-action-qt1 libunwind8
  libupstart-app-launch1 libvirtodbc0 libwireshark-data libwireshark3 libwiretap3 libwsutil3 libzip2 nepomuk-core-data ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 ofono
  oxygen-icon-theme p7zip-full powerd preview-latex-style ps2eps python-libtorrent python-numpy python3-gnupg python3-sip qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-folderlistmodel-plugin qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon sqlite3 syslinux-themes-debian syslinux-themes-debian-wheezy system-image-common system-image-dbus
  tex-gyre ttf-marvosym ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-touch-sounds ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme unetbootin-translations usermetricsservice virtuoso-minimal
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common wireshark-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  docbook-xml docbook-xsl fonts-droid libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libgpod4-nogtk libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl libnet-http-perl librarian0 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxml2-utils rarian-compat sgml-data unity-scope-video-remote
Suggested packages:
  docbook docbook-dsssl docbook-defguide dbtoepub docbook-xsl-doc-html docbook-xsl-doc-pdf docbook-xsl-doc-text docbook-xsl-doc docbook-xsl-saxon fop libsaxon-java libxalan2-java
  libxslthl-java xalan libdata-dump-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl libauthen-ntlm-perl perlsgml w3-recs opensp
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  account-plugin-google activity-log-manager activity-log-manager-control-center appmenu-qt apport-gtk apturl at-spi2-core bamfdaemon baobab bluez-cups checkbox-qt clementine colord
  compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-extra compizconfig-settings-manager copyq cups dbus-x11 deja-dup deja-dup-backend-gvfs deluge
  deluge-gtk dropbox eog evince evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-goa fbmessenger file-roller firefox flashplugin-installer freerdp-x11 friends friends-dispatcher gconf2 gcr
  gedit ghostscript-x gimp gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-nautilus-3.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gkbd-capplet gksu gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-calculator gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-datetime gnome-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer
  gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mines gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra
  gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine google-chrome-stable
  grub-customizer gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-x gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse hplip hud humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-gtk
  ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-table imagemagick indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-cpufreq indicator-keyboard indicator-multiload indicator-printers
  indicator-session indicator-sound indicator-sync intel-gpu-tools landscape-client-ui-install language-selector-gnome latex-beamer latex-xcolor latexmk libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libasound2-plugins libatk-adaptor libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-0
  libaudio2 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-perl libcairo2 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse
  libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango12 libcogl12 libcompizconfig0 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdbusmenu-qt2
  libdecoration0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers libespeak1 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libfarstream-0.1-0 libfarstream-0.2-2 libfluidsynth1 libfolks-eds25
  libframe6 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp1 libfriends0 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgbm1 libgcr-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3 libgdata13 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgegl-0.2-0 libgeis1 libgimp2.0 libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-glx libglade2-0 libglamor0 libglew1.8 libglewmx1.8 libglu1-mesa libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-control-center1
  libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0 libgphoto2-6 libgpod4 libgrail6 libgrip0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin
  libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgweather-3-3 libgxps2 libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7 libindicator7 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmagickcore5
  libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libmetacity-private0a libnautilus-extension1a libnm-gtk0 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnux-4.0-0 libpam-freerdp libpango-perl libpango1.0-0
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpangox-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpeas-1.0-0 libphonon4 libpocketsphinx1 libpoppler-glib8 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp
  libpurple0 libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-opengl libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt53d5 libqt5gui5 libqt5location5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-writer
  librhythmbox-core7 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsane libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl1.2debian libsmpeg0 libsphinxbase1 libstartup-notification0 libt1-5
  libtelepathy-farstream3 libtimezonemap1 libtotem0 libufe-xidgetter0 libunity-core-6.0-8 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps0 libva-x11-1
  libvdpau1 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvte-2.90-9 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck22 libx11-6 libxaw7 libxcb-composite0
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0
  libxcb-sync0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-util0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xv0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbfile1
  libxklavier16 libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxp6 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxres1 libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxvmc1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyelp0 libzbar0 light-themes lightdm
  lightdm-remote-session-freerdp lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure luatex mousetweaks mythes-en-us nautilus nautilus-image-tools nautilus-sendto nautilus-share
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd nux-tools nvidia-319-updates nvidia-settings-319-updates obex-data-server onboard
  onboard-data oneconf overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 pgf phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo policykit-1-gnome
  poppler-utils printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp prosper pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils
  python-appindicator python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-cairo python-compizconfig python-gi-cairo python-glade2 python-gnomekeyring python-gtk2 python-nautilus python-notify
  python-pygame python-qt4 python-ubuntu-sso-client python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-cairo python3-gi-cairo python3-pyatspi python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt4.phonon python3-uno
  qt-at-spi remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc sane-utils screen-resolution-extra seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui simple-scan sni-qt
  software-center software-properties-gtk ssh-askpass-gnome steam-launcher system-config-printer-gnome telepathy-haze telepathy-indicator texlive texlive-base texlive-binaries
  texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc
  texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texlive-pstricks
  texlive-pstricks-doc tipa tk8.6 tk8.6-lib ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-tweak unetbootin unity
  unity-asset-pool unity-greeter unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module unity-lens-applications unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-manpages unity-services unity-tweak-tool
  unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-service update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk vino vlc vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse wireshark x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-utils
  x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xauth xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xinit xinput xorg xsel xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-glamoregl
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-modesetting
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-s3
  xserver-xorg-video-savage xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xterm xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration yelp zeitgeist zeitgeist-datahub zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docbook-xml docbook-xsl fonts-droid libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libgpod4-nogtk libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl libnet-http-perl librarian0 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxml2-utils rarian-compat sgml-data unity-scope-video-remote
0 upgraded, 28 newly installed, 538 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6954 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2338 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

---

**EDIT**

I can try to do this (but it will have more or less the same output):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxcb1=1.9.1-3ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  content-hub deluge-common extlinux fonts-texgyre gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gsettings-ubuntu-touch-schemas libandroid-properties1 libboost-program-options1.53.0 libboost-python1.53.0
  libc-ares2 libcontent-hub0 libcpufreq0 libdee-qt5-3 libgflags2 libgfortran3 libgoogle-glog0 libgsettings-qt1 libhardware2 libhud2 libhybris libhybris-common1 liblapack3 libmedia1
  libmikmod2 libmirclient3 libmirplatform libmirprotobuf0 libmirserver7 libofono-qt1 libphonon4 libportmidi0 libqdjango-db0 libqt5organizer5 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects
  libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsmi2ldbl libsmpeg0 libsystemsettings1 libthumbnailer0 libtorrent-rasterbar7
  libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 libubuntu-application-api1 libubuntu-location-service0 libubuntu-platform-hardware-api1 libubuntudownloadmanager1 libunity-action-qt1 libunwind8
  libupstart-app-launch1 libwireshark-data libwireshark3 libwiretap3 libwsutil3 ofono p7zip-full powerd preview-latex-style ps2eps python-compizconfig python-libtorrent python-numpy
  python-pygame python3-gnupg python3-sip qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin qtdeclarative5-folderlistmodel-plugin qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin sqlite3 syslinux-themes-debian syslinux-themes-debian-wheezy
  system-image-common system-image-dbus tex-gyre ttf-marvosym ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-touch-sounds ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme unetbootin-translations
  usermetricsservice wireshark-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fonts-droid unity-lens-friends unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  account-plugin-google activity-log-manager activity-log-manager-control-center apport-gtk apturl bamfdaemon baobab bluez-cups clementine compiz compiz-gnome compiz-plugins
  compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-extra compizconfig-settings-manager copyq cups deja-dup deja-dup-backend-gvfs deluge deluge-gtk dropbox eog evince evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-goa fbmessenger file-roller firefox flashplugin-installer gcr gedit gimp gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gkbd-capplet gksu
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-datetime gnome-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity gnome-disk-utility
  gnome-font-viewer gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mines gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-canberra gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine google-chrome-stable
  grub-customizer gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-x gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x
  gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse hplip humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-table
  indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-cpufreq indicator-keyboard indicator-multiload indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sync
  intel-gpu-tools landscape-client-ui-install language-selector-gnome latex-beamer latex-xcolor latexmk libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-perl libcairo2 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango12 libcogl12 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3
  libfarstream-0.1-0 libfarstream-0.2-2 libfolks-eds25 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgcr-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata13 libgegl-0.2-0 libgimp2.0 libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglade2-0 libglamor0 libglew1.8 libglewmx1.8 libglu1-mesa libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0 libgrip0 libgtk-3-0
  libgtk-3-bin libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgweather-3-3 libgxps2 libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7 libindicator7
  libmagickcore5-extra libmetacity-private0a libnautilus-extension1a libnm-gtk0 libnux-4.0-0 libpango-perl libpango1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpeas-1.0-0
  libpoppler-glib8 libpurple0 libqt4-opengl libqt53d5 libqt5gui5 libqt5location5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqtwebkit4
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core7 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common
  libtelepathy-farstream3 libtimezonemap1 libtotem0 libufe-xidgetter0 libunity-core-6.0-8 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps0
  libvisual-0.4-plugins libvte-2.90-9 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwnck-3-0 libwnck22 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-image0 libxcb-shm0 libyelp0 light-themes
  lightdm-remote-session-freerdp lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure luatex mousetweaks mythes-en-us nautilus nautilus-image-tools nautilus-sendto nautilus-share
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd nux-tools nvidia-settings-319-updates onboard onboard-data oneconf overlay-scrollbar
  overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 pgf phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo policykit-1-gnome poppler-utils printer-driver-gutenprint
  printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp prosper python-appindicator python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-cairo python-gi-cairo python-glade2 python-gnomekeyring
  python-gtk2 python-nautilus python-notify python-qt4 python-ubuntu-sso-client python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-cairo python3-gi-cairo python3-pyatspi python3-pyqt4
  python3-pyqt4.phonon python3-uno remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc screen-resolution-extra seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui simple-scan
  software-center software-properties-gtk ssh-askpass-gnome steam-launcher synaptic system-config-printer-gnome telepathy-haze telepathy-indicator texlive texlive-base
  texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc
  texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texlive-pstricks
  texlive-pstricks-doc tipa ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-tweak unetbootin unity unity-asset-pool
  unity-greeter unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module unity-lens-applications unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-manpages unity-services unity-tweak-tool unity-webapps-common
  unity-webapps-service update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk vino vlc vlc-plugin-notify wireshark x11-utils xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xorg xserver-xorg-glamoregl
  xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration yelp zeitgeist zeitgeist-datahub zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-droid unity-lens-friends unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libxcb1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 357 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3188 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2039 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ppa-purge` then the packages will be correctly downgraded to Ubuntu's repositories versions.

```
$ sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get purge *libxcb*`

Comment: `autoremove` returns nothing and your `purge` line with `libxcb\*` will pretty much the same big list of packages to remove.